# Error inflating XML android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

First question posted, whoo!

Hello,
I'm implementing the CardView and RecyclerView libraries that are now included in the v7 android support library, but when the application runs, it quits when inflating the CardView layout. I've done a lot of looking around the web and found a few helpful things, but the problem remains.

I've imported the CardView and RecyclerView libraries according to the instructions given here: 
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res (I'm using Eclipse), and then I added them to the list of libraries referenced by the application I'm building (under Project Properties > Android > Libraries).
But it seems like at least the CardView library isn't imported properly, or the dependencies are wrong or something because the code seems right.

Here is the relevant part fragment with the RecyclerView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jamboree_info, container, false);
    return mLayout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    // make and set the adapter
    CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(mDataSet);
    recList.setAdapter(adapter);

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Here is R.layout.fragment_jamboree_info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the CardAdapter code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<ParseObject> mDataSet;

public CardAdapter(ArrayList<ParseObject> dataSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
}

// Size of the dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

/** Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder) */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView vTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
         super(v);
         vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TV_title);
    }
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override   
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    // ** This is where it crashes ** // 
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_jamboree_info, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.vTitle.setText(mDataSet.get(0).getString("title"));
}
```

}

And here is R.layout.card_jamboree_info -- this CardView seems to be the issue...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey_light"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="@string/basic_error" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Finally, at risk of too much information, here is the error log:

```
01-21 23:00:10.964: D/AndroidRuntime(15128): Shutting down VM
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): Process: com.evoqe, PID: 15128
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.evoqe.adapters.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:56)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.evoqe.adapters.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:1)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
01-21 23:00:10.980: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at andro
```

The code seems correct, so I'm suspicious that the issue is with dependencies. I followed these two tutorials when writing the code:

http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156
and 
treyrobinson.net/blog/android-l-tutorials-part-3-recyclerview-and-cardview/

Any help is massively appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added cardview lib as dependency in your gradle file?

Comment: with eclipse it is a problem, why not use studio? also eclipse adt is no longer in developement!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import the libs CardView,RecycleView and appcompat_v7 Internally , like firstly remove appcompat_v7 from your project as *Project>properties>Android > remove Apply and Ok * and then import  reclyce View , Card View and appcompat_v7  and (appcompat_v4 if it is needed)  from your HardDrive  it into your project libs folder and then add it from project>Properties>JavaBuildPath >Add Jar instead of Add external Jar then choose libraries from your project libs folder . Then You need to change  **Theme in styles.xml**.

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

and same in other styles.xml

as Appcompat.Light is no more suppported after removing .

Then clean and run . Hope it might works !

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything from solutions then need to check this minor mistake that i did before.

if your manifest file that has target sdk version to **21**. not below this.

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11" //anything you need
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

because after trying everything on internet i solved recyclerview inflating error by changing target from **17** to **21**.

may be this can help for someone in future and not wasting days behind it as i did.